# Media queries overriding each other - weird situation

Tags: css, media-queries

My iPhoneX media query is overriding all of my other media queries. All of my other media queries accept their coirreect screen sizes using min/max width.. but for some reason IphoneX makes all of the other media queries invalid. Could anyone help?

```
/* images */

img{
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* Header image */

  .headerImg{
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  /* Title */

  .title{
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  /* voting buttons */

  .vote{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  #vote1 .dot{
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 15px;
    border: 2px solid white;
  }

  #vote2 .dot{
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 24px;
    border: 2px solid white;
  }

  /* GLOBAL CLASSES */

  .flexCenter{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
  }

  .paddingTopBottom{
     padding: 10px 0;
  }

<!-- iPhone4/4s -->
<link href="https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/vaf4d25yesa" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)">  
<!-- iPhone5s/5c/5se -->
<link href="https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/asgp1bospyf" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px)">  
<!-- iPhone6/6s/7/8 -->
<link href="https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/c3c1pf4b2me" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px)">
<!-- iPhone6+/7+/8+ -->
<link href="https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/qjhe5zmjrys" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px)">
<!-- iPhoneX -->
<link href="https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/ioeyyyvvogl" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px)">
```

And here are the linked media queries.

```
/* Media queries for mobile sizes */

/* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) { 
    .headerImg{max-width: 280px !important;padding-top: 50px !important}
    .title{max-width: 280px !important;padding-bottom: 50px !important;padding-top: 25px !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 115px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 11px !important;left: 15px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 11px !important;left: 9px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 120px !important;}
    .sc-button{height: 45px !important; width: 160px !important;}
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) { 
    .headerImg{max-width: 280px !important;padding-top: 20px !important}
    .title{max-width: 280px !important;padding-bottom: 40px !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 115px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 13px !important;left: 17px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 13px !important;left: 11px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 80px !important;}
    .sc-button{height: 45px !important; width: 160px !important;}
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) { 
    .headerImg{max-width: 280px !important;padding-top: 20px !important}
    .title{max-width: 280px !important;padding: 10px 0 !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 115px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 11px !important;left: 15px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 11px !important;left: 9px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 80px !important;}
    .sc-button{height: 45px !important; width: 160px !important;}
}

/* ----------- iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    .headerImg{max-width: 200px !important;padding-top: 20px !important}
    .title{max-width: 200px !important;padding: 10px 0 !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 100px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 7px !important;left: 15px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 7px !important;left: 9px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 60px !important;}
}

/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .headerImg{max-width: 170px !important;}
    .title{max-width: 160px !important;padding: 10px 0 !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 110px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 7px !important;left: 15px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 7px !important;left: 9px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 60px !important;}
}

/* ----------- Galaxy S4, S5 and Note 3 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and {
    .headerImg{max-width: 240px !important;padding-top: 50px !important}
    .title{max-width: 240px !important;padding-bottom: 40px !important;padding-top: 15px !important;}
    .deal{max-width: 115px !important;}
    .vote {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    #vote1 .dot {top: 9px !important;left: 15px !important;width: 10px !important;; height: 10px !important;}
    #vote2 .dot {top: 9px !important;left: 9px !important;width: 10px !important;; height: 10px !important;}
    .smartcapture-submit-button-wrapper{bottom: 90px !important;}
    .sc-button{height: 45px !important; width: 160px !important;}
}
```

When i remove !important from the media queries, none are picked up and instead only the default styles.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Erayner,

Media queries can be tricky...

If you have the iPhone 4 media query statements below the iPhone 6,7&8 media query statements, it will (in fact) override the iPhone 6,7&8 one because it's listed below it. The CSS file gets read top to bottom.  For example:

```
<style>
.className {
  width: 50%;
}
.className {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

the second `.className` with the width of `100%` will take since it is last (being read from top to bottom).

Another reason it is overriding because the iPhone 4 media query has a range of 320px to 480px while the iPhone 6,7&8 one has a range that falls within the iPhone 4's range (375px to 667px).  375 through 480px fall in the iPhone 4's range...and since it is below the iPhone 6,7&8's code, it takes precedence...

Also, not sure why you have sooo many `!important` calls - May help us better to understand your particular situation better if you provide your entire css file to understand the ordering of your IDs and Classes.

**Have you tried placing the iPhone 4's media query code above the iPhone 6,7& 8's?  And if so, are you having the same issue?**

Comment: Hey Michael, I've narrowed down the problem, and found that iPhoneX media query is the culprit. I'll update my question with the necessary code to help explain better. Thanks!

Comment: Just realised i'm a huge noob.. I could just use device-height instead of width.. I thought I was using height! Thanks for your time and input. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your iPhone 4 `@media` rules before the iPhone 6 ones. So the iPhone 6 will then override iPhone 4 when the width is 375px or higher.

The rule below will apply when width is between 320px and 374px..

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {...}
```

The rule below will override when width is between 375px and 667px;

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){...}
```